# How can i search with month and year in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert a MySQL query to T-SQL, I need date format function for that, 
this is my query in MySQL:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN ('241') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(t.period,"%Y-%m") = '2017-09'
```

I am getting error, `'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name`, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @PeterB the SQL Server equivalent would be [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) (specially, for this example `FORMAT(t.period, 'yyyy-MM')`. I, however, never recommend the use of that function; it's awfully slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both databases, it is better to write this using explicit date comparisons:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target t LEFT JOIN
     tb_keyindicator k
     ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN ('241') AND
      t.period >= '2017-09-01' AND
      t.period < '2017-10-01';
```

Note that if `branch_id` is a number, then you should drop the single quotes for the comparison.

By using direct date comparisons, either SQL engine can take advantage of an appropriate index on the column.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning: a good reason to do it this way is that if there is an INDEX on the `period` field, it will now be used. By using any kind of formatting or converting to varchar, that advantage will never occur because it will first convert all values and then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date to yyyy-mm format if you wish,

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN ('241') 
AND CONVERT(char(7), t.period, 121) = '2017-09'
```

Comment: Although does provide a solution, this query isn't SARGable (due to the use of `CONVERT` on a column in the `WHERE` clause). For a large dataset, it's going to suffer performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by month:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.value, 
       t.branch_id, 
       k.name 
FROM tb_target t LEFT JOIN
tb_keyindicator k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN ('241') AND
      datepart(month, t.period) = 9
```

Comment: This would suffer the same issue I noted on sanatsathyan's answer. Also, it's worth noting that this would pick up results for September, regardless of year. The OP was specifically also filtering for 2017.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN ('241') 
AND LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, t.period,112),6) = '2017-09'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.